# Primitive Roots of Unity and THE primtive root of unity

Tags: complex-numbers

If a question states that $\omega_n$ is THE primitive complex root of unity of order $n$, then does this always imply that $\omega_n$ = $e^{2\pi i/n}$, i.e. primitive roots of unity of order $n$ are those complex numbers such that $\omega_n = e^{2\pi ij/n}$ for which $j$ is such that $0 < j < n$ and $gcd(j,n)$= 1, but if a question asks for THE primitive root, can it be taken as the case $j=1$?

Comment: as I know there is no "the" primitive root, just that it should not be $1$.

Comment: @KingTut there are other roots of unity that are not primitive and not 1 though..?

Comment: A question shouldn't ask for *the* primitive $n$th root of unity (unless $n$ is 1 or 2). If it does, the person asking the question had better have previously given a precise definition, so others can know what she means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation amounts to solutions for $\omega^n=1$.

The solution for this is $\omega=\exp{(2\pi i j/n)}$.

The solution is `primitive` when the $\gcd(j,n)=1$, which means that the first power to equal 1, is when n divides the power.

The solution is `THE primitive` exactly when $j=1$.

The reason for this, is that isomorphisms are used to project the primitive (which is taken as the identity in isomorphisms), onto other solutions.  The same situation occurs in

$x^2=4$.  Thus, $2$ and $-2$ are square roots of $4$, but $x=2$ is THE square root of $4$.

Comment: What is your source for this, wendy? It's not a distinction I can recall ever seeing anyone make.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am not sure what you mean by source.  It's a distinction one makes to deal with polygonal isomorphism.

Comment: I mean, who exactly makes that distinction? Where does it say (other than in your answer) that $e^{2\pi i/n}$ is *the* primitive root? Can you cite a textbook, or a paper?

Comment: The people who use cyclotomic numbers as a basis of a number system make this distinction.  For example, a particular transform is to replace $\exp{2\pi i j/n}$ by $\exp{2\pi i jk/n}$, which transforms a polygon into one of its transforms.  It's the solution to Coxeter's isomorphism problem.  But i ultimately rely on pictures I saw in Gauss's "Discussion on Arithmetic" i saw when i was 12 or something.

Comment: You and I must have different editions of the Disquisitiones – mine doesn't have any pictures in it.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments to the question, mathematicians do not in general speak of "the" primitive $n$th root of unity because all such roots behave isomorphically.

There are cases where choosing different primitive roots can give disagreeing results because of some outside convention not inherent to the roots. For instance, we can use the theory of quadratic Gauss sums to render

$\zeta-\zeta^2-\zeta^3+\zeta^4 = \sqrt5,$

where $\zeta$ is a primitive fifth root of unity; but if we apply the usual definition that the square root should be nonnegative then the relation holds only if we choose a $\zeta$ candidate with a positive real part. But even here that admits a pair of complex-conjugate choices, so none emerges as deterministically "the" primitive fifth root of unity with respect to the Gauss-sum relation.